# NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with index 1 executing select_by_index in loop through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

Page has the following selection box,

```
<div class="select select-gender select-container">
  <select name="gender" class="my-dropdown 115px option" data-field="gender" data-type="dropdown">
    <option value="female">Woman</option>
    <option value="male">Man</option>
    <option value="">All</option> 
  </select>
</div>
```

Python code

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
while True:
...
    # status off
    status_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "status")))
    if not(status_btn.is_selected()): # If checkbox is unticked
        status_btn.click() # to tick it

    # no photos
    photo_btn = driver.find_element_by_name("photo")
    if photo_btn.is_selected(): # If checkbox is ticked
        photo_btn.click() # to untick it

    #index gender
    # 0 woman
    # 1 man
    gen_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('gender'))
    print(gen_select)
    gen_select.select_by_index(1)
```

It works fine for the first few passes though the loop and then produced this error, the print shows it got the select element and the "object at" is not the old object but it's failing to select it.

```
<selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x000001B2DB740438>
<selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x000001B2DCF189B0>
<selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x000001B2DB753F98>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LFmale2.py", line 94, in <module>
    gen_select.select_by_index(1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 103, in select_by_index
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with index %d" % index)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with index 1
```

Comment: Turns out there is nothing wrong with the code other than I've split the select by index. Select(driver.find_element_by_name('gender')).select_by_index(0) is correct. I had a large number or orphaned headless browsers from every run that had an error. As they accumulated it made it more likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with index 1
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance was unable to locate any element with index 1

I am a bit surprised at the fact that *`...works fine for the first few passes though the loop...`* due to the following reasons:

### select_by_index(index)

[**`select_by_index(index)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_index) selects the option at the given index. This is done by examing the `index` attribute of an element, and not merely by counting.

The *HTML* which you have provided doesn't reflects the `index` attribute. So ideally the following line:

```
gen_select.select_by_index(1)
```

Should have raised an exception in the very first iteration.

### Solution

The relevant HTML contains **visible_text** for all the three options:

- `Woman`
- `Man`
- `All`

So as per best practice you should use the [**`select_by_visible_text(text)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_visible_text).

- Code Block:

  ```
  gen_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('gender'))
  print(gen_select)
  gen_select.select_by_visible_text("Man")
  ```

Comment: The `<option>`s don't have `index` attribute in the html, but the [option object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp) behind it does.

Comment: @Guy **index** is one of the `Option Object Property`. You have to assign some **value** to this property for _Selenium_ to realize/detect this property before performing any action. Hence the documentation mentions _...done by examing the index attribute of an element, and not merely by counting..._. let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: It wasn't a question. Selenium doesn't realize anything, each `option` has `index` attribute based on its position in the drop down list as part of `option object` properties. Selenium just read this property.